# double upsert in Node.js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var urlSchema = new Schema ( {
url : String,
visitor : [{name: String,date: Date}],
counter : Number
});

var url = mongoose.model('url',urlSchema);
var domain = blah blah;
var conditions = { url: domain };
var update = { $inc : {counter:1},
              $push : { visitor: [{
                  name: data.username,
                  date: new Date()
                  }]
              }
             };
var options = {upsert: true};
url.update(conditions,update,options,function(err){
if(err){
  console.log(err);
}else{
  console.log('A domain successfully added to DB');
}
```

Currently I am using the schema and code above to make an access counter for each page.
It upserts url documents which is counting total access and holding access user info.
so far so good It's working properly.

now I want to add "counter : Number" in visitor array and when the event occurs, if the user is already in visitor array,I want to update that instead of pushing new one.
But I have no idea how to make the 'double upsert' command.
is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit difficult even impossible perform a query that satisfy your condition. I have reproduced your scenario with following query

```
url.findOne({'url': 'search.php', 'visitor.name': "JohnDoe"},
    function (err, visitor) {
        if (visitor) {
            url.update(
                {
                    'url': 'search.php', 'visitor.name': "JohnDoe"
                },
                {
                    $inc: {'visitor.$.counter': 1, 'counter': 1}
                },
                function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error occured")
                    } else {
                        console.log("Success");
                    }

                });
        } else {
            var conditions = { url: 'search.php' };
            var update = { $inc : {counter:1},
                $push : { visitor: [{
                    name: data.username,
                    date: new Date(),
                    counter: 0
                }]
                }
            };
            var options = {upsert: true};
            url.update(conditions,update,options,function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log('A domain successfully added to DB');
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Simple, insert if not exists with counter = 0, update if exists with incrementing counter by 1